# How to print math symbols (using latex) like sigma with f-strings?

Tags: python, printing, latex, mathjax, f-string

```
x = np.array([5,4,3])
y = np.array([1,2,3])
print(f"{sum(x*y)}, {sum(x**2)}, {sum(y**2)}")
#> 22, 50, 14
```

I want to print with the mathematical symbols displayed
[image: \sum{x*y}]

But when I use f-string

```
print(f"$\sum{xy}$ = {sum(x*y)}, $\sum{x^2}$ = {sum(x**2)}, , $\sum{y^2}$ = {sum(y**2)}")
```

I get error: `NameError: name 'xy' is not defined`.
Seems like f-strings are not able to recognize latex code.

What's the solution here?

Comment: `print` prints to the terminal. The terminal doesn't support latex code, so neither does `print.` You are going to have to print it somewhere else. Also it appears that latex code uses `{}` which have special meaning in an f string

Comment: You'll need to escape the curly braces to use them in an f-string.

Comment: You're right, f-strings are not able to render latex code. You will likely need to use a GUI in your script to do so.

Comment: Is there any other way to use mathematical symbols?

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr: python can't print LaTex to terminal.

Usually, terminals are text only. That means that special LaTeX images cannot be displayed.

However, there are some ways that you can still view LaTeX (though not through terminal).

For example, you can call `pdflatex` through terminal (assuming you have it installed)

```py
import os

latex = "Insert Latex Code here"
with open("latex.tex", "w") as file:
    file.write(latex)

os.system("pdflatex latex.tex")
```

Your LaTeX should be rendered as a pdf called `latex.pdf`

Answer (score -2):

I’m not sure I understood your question correctly, but the reason for the error is that Python recognizes the curly braces in your latex code and tries to format it as usual in the f-String, therefore not finding the `xy` variable, as it doesn’t exist.

You have to escape the latex braces using double braces:

```py
print(f"$\sum{{xy}}$ = {sum(x*y)}, and so on...”)
```

Comment: Tried `print(f"$\sum{{xy}}$ = {sum(x*y)}")`. Got : `$\sum{xy}$ = 22`